# 'data-disable-with' triggering all the buttons on the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two button in a multi-step form: CONTINUE and BACK.

```
<%= f.button_tag "#{t :Back}", name: 'back_button', id: 'back_button', class: "btn btn-primary", style:"background: #d3f0fe !important; color: #44B5EB !important;", 'data-disable-with' =>"<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> #{t :processing}".html_safe unless @event.first_step? %>

<%= f.button_tag "#{t :Continue}", id: 'submit-all', class: "btn btn-primary", 'data-disable-with' =>"<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> #{t :processing}".html_safe %>
```

I added the following JS to disable one button when the user click on the other one:

```
$('#back_button').click( function () {
    var buttons = $('#back_button').not($(this));
    buttons.removeAttr('data-disable-with');
    buttons.attr('disabled', true);
});



$('#submit-all').click( function () {
    var buttons = $('#submit-all').not($(this));
    buttons.removeAttr('data-disable-with');
    buttons.attr('disabled', true);
});
```

but for some reason it does not work and both buttons turn into "Processing" when either one is clicked on.

Does anyone sees something wrong in the code please?

Comment: Not really sure about your `var buttons = $('#back_button').not($(this));` why do you need to specify `not($(this));`?  Sounds like you only need to write `var buttons = $('#back_button');`

Comment: Hey, i used the not($(this)) to remove the attribute data-disable-with

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
$('#back_button').click( function () {
    var buttons = $('#submit-all');
    buttons.removeAttr('data-disable-with');
    buttons.attr('disabled', true);
});



$('#submit-all').click( function () {
    var buttons = $('#back_button');
    buttons.removeAttr('data-disable-with');
    buttons.attr('disabled', true);
});
```